# Configure child class as a Bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have two classes as `AMapper` and `BMapper`. `BMapper` is extended by `AMapper`. `AMapper` is extended by `AbstractMapper`.

```
package core.springtest;

public abstract class AbstractMapper
{
  public void map()
  {
    // Mapping logic goes here.
  }
}
```

Following are the implementations of Mapper.

```
package core.springtest;

public class AMapper extends AbstractMapper
{

  @Override
  public void map()
  {
    super.map();
    // Mapper logic goes here.
  }
}


package core.springtest;

public class BMapper extends AMapper
{

  @Override
  public void map()
  {
    super.map();
    // Mapper logic goes here.
  }
}
```

And I want to configure these two implementations and its implementation as follows,

```
package core.springtest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration("core.springtest.Configuration")
public class Configuration
{
  @Bean(name = "core.springtest.AMapper")
  public AMapper getAMapper()
  {
    return new AMapper();
  }

  @Bean(name = "core.springtest.BMapper")
  public BMapper getBMapper()
  {
    return new BMapper();
  }

}
```

And when I try to start the server it gives following error,

expected single matching bean but found 2: `core.springtest.AMapper,core.springtest.BMapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject these into other beans, you need to qualify by name with either Spring's `Qualifier` annotation, or Java's `Named` annotation.

You can't inject by type because `AMapper` extends `BMapper` and an instance of `BMapper` (i.e. itself) is a bean too.